# Receiving an array with MPI

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I am attempting to make a parallel program that merge sorts two arrays that are being sent to each other from separate processes. In this simplified version, where I am attempting to get the communication to work, I wish to simply send one array (length of four unsigned integers) from process 0 to process 1, then print both the local and received arrays in process 1. Here is the code for this. (Load_and_distribute simply fills the arrays, and I have checked to ensure that both processes do indeed have four unsigned integers within).

```
int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int ret;
  unsigned int ln, tn;
  unsigned int * lvals;
  int rank, size;

  ret = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  assert(MPI_SUCCESS == ret);

/* get information about MPI environment */
  ret = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  assert(MPI_SUCCESS == ret);
  ret = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  assert(MPI_SUCCESS == ret);

  load_and_distribute(argv[1], &ln, &lvals);

  unsigned int rn;
  unsigned int * rvals;

  rvals = malloc(4*sizeof(*rvals));

 if(rank == 0){
    MPI_Send(&lvals, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  else if (rank == 1){
    rvals[0] = 4;
    MPI_Recv(&rvals, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("lvals = %d %d %d %d\n",lvals[0],lvals[1],lvals[2],lvals[3]);
    printf("rvals = %d %d %d %d\n",rvals[0],rvals[1],rvals[2],rvals[3]);
  } 

  ret = MPI_Finalize();
  assert(MPI_SUCCESS == ret);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The send and receive seems to go through without a fit, but when it attempts to print the rval values, I arrive at this output, and I am unsure why.

```
[hpc5:04355] *** Process received signal ***
[hpc5:04355] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[hpc5:04355] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[hpc5:04355] Failing at address: 0xe0c4ac
[hpc5:04355] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf370)[0x7f2a8d23c370]
[hpc5:04355] [ 1] ./hms_mpi[0x40165d]
[hpc5:04355] [ 2] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f2a8ce8db35]
[hpc5:04355] [ 3] ./hms_mpi[0x400c29]
[hpc5:04355] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 4355 on node hpc5 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct buffers for `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` are `lvals` and `rvals` (e.g. do **not** use the `&` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Remove & in your MPI_Send and MPI_Recv:

```
MPI_Send(lvals, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Recv(rvals, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

It is working like this:

```
int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
```

buf: initial address of send buffer (choice)*